# If a tube has perforations at the outflow end, does flow increase?

Tags: fluid-dynamics, flow

[image: Flow through cylindrical tube vs end sealed with side perforations]

Does total water flow out of a tube increase if there are some perforations on the tube that have a greater cross sectional area? As per the attached image, let's say we have two tubes:

1. Tube 1: 10 cm long; 1 cm internal diameter; 100 mmHg pressure difference at the inflow. Both ends are open.
2. Tube 2: As above, except that the outflow end is closed and instead there are seven 0.5 cm diameter perforations on the side of tube.

Is the flow greater with Tube 2, or does the initial inflow area create a bottleneck and render outflow equal, since the inflow diameter is equivalent between the two tubes? My suspicion is that the flow through Tube 2 will be somewhat greater because there is an increased outflow area and probably less friction. Or, are the parameters for the Hagen–Poiseuille equation equal between the two tubes, resulting in equal outflow?

Comment: The velocity is not dependent on the area of the output in Bernoulli's Equation, so yes. But it probably doesn't strongly apply because of the situation, so it doesn't really tell you what the answer is.

Comment: Assuming an inviscid fluid, why not analyze this using the Bernoulli equation and see what you get?

Comment: I think you both, Aseku and Chet, are correct. I should use Bernoulli's equation. It would seem that whatever goes in must come out. Since there is a relatively larger cross-sectional outflow area, it would seem that outflow velocity would be slower over a larger area-but with same volume out as in.